# Check IBOutlet from UIView debugging IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am using `UIView` debugging to see why layout position is wrong or why I have set text wrongly.

When I do `UIView` debug, I saw like this. I only saw `UILabel` and I don't know what`IBOutlet` I set to. May I know if it is possible what kind of outlet I set? or identify what is that`UILabel` and find inside my code?

[image]